# Cannot resolve symbol 'EnableEurekaClient'

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix, service-discovery

I'm configuring eureka server and eureka client for spring boot microservices.
Spring boot version - 3.3.0-SNAPSHOT
spring-cloud.version - 2023.0.0
java - 17

When I add **@EnableEurekaClient** annotation at main class, it is not able to find the annotation.

Getting this error-
java: cannot find symbol
symbol: class EnableEurekaClient

I have tried both of the following dependencies-

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Full pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.bio</groupId>
    <artifactId>security</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>security</name>
    <description>Security Server</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

My application.properties

```
server.port=8081

spring.cloud.compatibility-verifier.enabled=false

eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
```

Comment: Please add your full pom.xml

Comment: Why have you set `spring.cloud.compatibility-verifier.enabled` to `false`? That's something you should never really set apart from some extremely limited scenarios when you are aware that the versions are not compatible and want to check sth, for example. Do you get `'scopedTarget.eurekaClient` with the pom above?

Comment: @OlgaMaciaszek I was getting this error - `Spring Boot [3.3.0-SNAPSHOT] is not compatible with this Spring Cloud release train`. I was also aware that different versions are incompatible, but in my case, that won't have an impact on the project's other features.

Comment: All sorts of things may go wrong if you use incompatible versions, including like the scopedTarget error you've cited under the other response.

Comment: Can you please guide how to set compatible versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `@EnableDiscoveryClient` instead of `@EnableEurekaClient`.

However `@EnableEurekaClient` annotation is not required anymore. Simply adding `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client` to dependencies will enable the client. https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/4022#issuecomment-915991198

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but got another error - Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.eurekaClient' defined in class path resource

Comment: That should be due to some other issues. Can you share your entire pom file?

Comment: Here is the [Github link](https://github.com/patilshubham7024/bio/blob/c6a4df8dd6c682446654bf8cf561be3522645f5d/security/pom.xml) of my pom file.

Comment: Link is not accessible. Maybe due to permissions.

Comment: Please check the pom.xml added into the question.

Comment: Using `<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>` instead of `<artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>` can resolve the issue.

Comment: Thank you @Shanan this change has worked.

Answer (score -1):

Hello this worked for me.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2023.0.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Otherwise maybe your properties are not set right.

Comment: I'm already doing this.

Comment: Have you tried these configs?  
spring.application.name=my-eureka-client
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true